# Page crashing on large amount of rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, browser, datatable

I have 17,861 rows in an AJAX response which runs in a few seconds. The record is not appended into the table due to page crashing. I have also used JavaScript handlebars.js template

Can anyone guide me on it how to control big large rows in the browser?

```
$.each(result, function (index, elem) {
  const obj = {};
}
```

This loop runs 17,861 times for my case.

Comment: Do you need all the data at once? Maybe you should paginate.

Comment: That's far too many rows to handle in a single operation. I would suggest you implement server side filtering and paging of your data set, and then return 50-100 rows at a time.

Comment: But It's a client report and it can not be in load as paginate.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan

Comment: @zoltalar I have used data tables pagination but clients a year data of the company required.

Comment: Can I show you my Datatables function?
@GeoHalkiadakis

Comment: I suspect you might want to breakdown the results into smaller peices or perform more work on the server side. For example, you could have the server side generate all the proper HTML for the results, formatting everything so that the AJAX call gets HTML back ready to use instead of JSON. This way you could switch to `.load()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the rows to show according to scroll position of container. Of course it would be best to find a plugin that does that.

Here's an example from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-data-grid-for-millions-of-rows-in-javascript/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>1 Million Rows Demo</title>
  <link id="themecss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/css/light/all.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/js/shieldui-all.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body class="theme-light">
  <div id="grid" style="margin-bottom: -500px;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      var grid = new shield.DataSource({
        remote: {
          operations: ["skip", "take"],
          read: function(params, success, error) {
            var skip = grid.skip || 0,
              take = grid.take || 20,
              data = [],
              k = 96;

            for (var i = skip; i < skip + take; i++) {
              k++;
              var row = {};
              for (var j = 1; j < 3; j++) {
                row["Counting"] = i + 1;
                if (k == 123)
                  k = 97;
                var string = String.fromCharCode(k);
                row["Alphabets"] = string;
              }
              data.push(row);
            }
            success({
              data: data,
              total: 1000000
            });
          }
        },
        schema: {
          data: "data",
          total: "total"
        }
      });
      $("#grid").shieldGrid({
        dataSource: grid,
        height: 400,
        scrolling: {
          virtual: true
        },
        columns: (function() {
          var cols = [];

          cols.push({
            field: "Counting",
            width: 140
          });

          cols.push({
            field: "Alphabets",
            width: 140
          });
          return cols;
        })()
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can work with data table pagination?